# Rename-item thinks variable is a path

Tags: powershell, rename, rename-item-cmdlet

I'm trying to rename a file but powershell thinks my variable is a string and fails.

Here is the script:

```
$date=(get-date -Format d)
$time=(get-date -Format t)
$source = "D:\_qapi.log"
$newfilename = "$date"+"_"+"$time"+"_qapi[SERVERNAME].log"

Rename-Item $source -NewName $newfilename
```

And here is the error:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because the target specified represents a path or device name.
```

Anyone know I can fix this? For some reason powershell sees the $date variable in $newfilename as a path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its illegal characters in the date time strings.

this works:

```
$date=(get-date -Format d) -replace("/")
$time=(get-date -Format t) -replace(":")
$source = "D:\_qapi.log"
$newfilename = "$date"+"_"+"$time"+"_qapi[$env:Computername].log"

Rename-Item $source -NewName $newfilename
```